# How to make netrw ignore new local files?

Tags: netrw

I've set up an autocmd to automatically create directories of the filepath I'm writing to: `au BufWritePre,FileWritePre * call <SID>EnsureDir(expand('<afile>:p:h'))`. This prevents creating directories when I discard the buffer.

I'd like to continue to be able to use stdin, provide url filepaths, and read files into buffers from within vim as normal. But how can I use netrw's features yet prevent it's FileExplorer autocmd (on `VimEnter`) to act on new/nonexistent, local files? What's a good approach to this?

---

<sup>I hope it's clear what i'm asking. I'm suprised that I could not find a similar question. I read pi_netrw.txt, but could not find a method there. I use neovim version 0.2.2 on linux 4.14.3-1-ARCH.</sup>

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. You're talking about writing to new dirs/files after you've started Vim so how does a `VimEnter` autocommand pose a problem?

Comment: I'm so sorry. When testing with a `-u testrc.vim`, I did not properly check all scriptnames. There's a custom file in `/usr/share/..` that has a function which is resolving the autocmd match on BufNewFile I forgot about. I added an `isdirectory` check, and now everything is fine.

Comment: That's okay. Glad you got it straightened out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing, I could not disable plugins. I forgot about a file in `/usr/local/share/nvim/site/...` It turns out that I silently ran a `bwipeout` and `edit` when incorrectly handling `<amatch>` on a `BufNewFile` autocmd. I simplified my knotty setup and included a simple `isdirectory()` check.

netrwPlugin.vim behaves as expected (at least for my usage). sorry.